# When is "顔" かお or がお?

Tags: words, kanji, readings

I've recently read about the slang that came from Kansai-ben, "どや顔" (doyagao) and realized that 顔 was spelt as "がお" instead of "かお". This is my first time seeing this so I was wondering what caused the reading to change.